# map is not centered in tabpanel extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am having a tab panel with three tabs. Third tab is to display map. I am getting map with required controls but it is not centered. Point is toward more north west than center of tab. So I have to drag the map to bring the point to center of Tab.

Tab panel code

```
var infoPanel = new Ext.tab.Panel({
    id: 'guestTabPan',
    xtype: 'tabpanel',
    title: 'Site Information',
    autoDestroy: false,
    items:[
      {
        id: 'siteTab',
        title:'Site',
        items:[
           ....
        ]
      },{
        title: 'Pressure',
        id: 'pressureTab',
        items:[
          .....
        ]
      },{
        title: 'Map',
        id: 'mapTab',
        items:[ 
          {
            xtype: "panel",
            id: 'mapTabPanel',
            height: 1000,                         
            layout: 'fit',
            items:[
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  });
```

Map code

```
 var smallGoogleMap = {xtype: 'gmappanel',id :'gSmallSiteMap',width:'100%',height:1000,
            zoomLevel:10,
            gmapType: 'map',
            mapConfOpts: ['enableScrollWheelZoom','enableDoubleClickZoom','enableDragging'],
            mapControls: ['GSmallMapControl','GMapTypeControl','NonExistantControl'],
            setCenter: {
              lat: SiteLat,
              lng: SiteLng,
              marker:{ title: SiteTitle}
            }

};

Ext.getCmp('mapTabPanel').add(smallGoogleMap);
```

any guess?

Comment: Try removing `width:'100%',height:1000` because your parent component already has layout:fit. Also try to minify your nesting. There is no config `setCenter` for a gmappanel. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I will try removing width and height.To give answer about setCenter than it is giving me center point as desired, I am not executing any event on it.I will search around config if there is any but to get idea what kind of config are you suggesting for setcenter ?

Comment: I tried removing width:'100%',height:1000 but it didn't work ! I was optimistic because as you said parent container is 'fit' but it gives me white tab not even gray so map even didn't generate.

Comment: Too bad. sorry that it didn't work but I have not an answer to your question really. I hope someone with more GMAP experience is gonna solve this for you. good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call this.getMap().setcenter of GMapPanel.js on activation of the tab that helps centered your map. It works for me. Now setCenter is not the separate method at least not the js file I have so, I added center point of map on activate event of Map Tab as below,

```
{
   title: 'Map',
   id: 'mapTab',
   listeners: {
    'activate':{
       fn:function(){
         var gsm = Ext.getCmp('gSmallSiteMap');
         var mpoint = new GLatLng(mymarker.lat,mymarker.lng);
         gsm.addMarker(mpoint,mymarker.marker,false,true, mymarker.listeners);
       }
     }  
   },
   items:[ 
          ......
         ]
}
```